# How to restrict renaming a file in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to restrict renaming a exported file in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)?

Comment: export db data in ods,xls,csv files in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a readonly attribute when the file is created. That will help, but is not foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean setting the filter for the filedialog. In that case *[FileDialog.Filter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText)*  (MSDN) will help.